# Infinite Sum of the Reciprocal of the Inverse Harmonic Number Function

Tags: sequences-and-series, harmonic-numbers

It's a very strange question I know, but I am trying to figure out the infinite series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac {1}{H^{(-1)}_k}$ where $H^{(-1)}_k$ is the inverse of the harmonic number function generalized to all reals. I tried to put it into Wolfram Alpha, but the only way I could figure out to express $H^{(-1)}_k$ was in terms of the $\psi^{(-1)}$ function which they don't have.

Comment: Do you need the harmonic number to be generalized to all reals? Why?

Comment: @i707107 The Harmonic Number function only takes positive integers, and except for the case of $H_1$ the result is not an ingeger, so therefore it needs to be generalized so that positive integers become part of its domain.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I know, that's why the term in the denominator is the inverse of the harmonic number function. The inverse of the harmonic number function grows quite quickly.

Comment: @Bakmoon And what generalization do you prefer?

Comment: @Constructor I just want to generalize it so that its inverse can accept positive integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One "generalization" is to let $F(x)$ be the least positive integer $n$ for which
$H_n \ge x$.  Now $H_n = \ln(n) + \gamma + 1/(2n) + O(1/n^2)$, so
$F(x) \approx \exp(x - \gamma - 1/(2x) + O(1/x^2))$.  In particular
$\sum_{k=1}^\infty 1/F(k)$ converges.  Of course I don't know exactly what
the sum is.  But from using the exact values for $k = 1$ to $7$ and numerical
approximation from there on, I estimate it to be about $1.392189$.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but what does the O as in the expression $O(1/x^2)$ indicate as a function?

Comment: The most obvious generalization is $H^{-1}(k)=\psi^{-1}(k-\gamma)-1$ I think.

Comment: @Bakmoon It is a [big $O$ notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation).

Comment: @Constructor Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

$\dfrac{H_{k+1}^{-1}}{H_k^{-1}}\approx3$, so the series decreases exponentially, and therefore converges. By using *Mathematica's*

`FindRoot` function, the numerical value $S=1.419878024238479212425700930495898499^+$ was obtained, for which the [Inverse Symbolic Calculator](http://isc.carma.newcastle.edu.au/advanced) and [Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences](http://oeis.org) are unable to return anything. Hope this helps.